# Handle API URLs in Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

## Overview:

I'm starting to program in Swift, I'm making an application to order food, to manage the API using Alamofire, so I'm using mamp to test the server.

I was thinking about the correct way to handle API URLs, for example, using "localhost / api / action" and i'm going to use "myApp.com/api/accion" when the application becomes real.

## My thoughts:

I was thinking about using a JSON to save all my URLs and then when the applications go into production I do not have to move all the code, only the JSON.

But I think,there should be a better way to do it, so any ideas would really help me, remember that I'm really new and really, thank you for wasting your time reading this.

## Questions:

- How to handle the URLs for Dev and Prod ?

Comment: This is called HTTP routing. Every web framework has its own solution, but in any case, I would advise you not to bother re-inventing the wheel. Just use a web framework that implements it for you.

Comment: Lol your question has a single sentence, and 13 commas. The question would be better received if you took the time to improve the quality, clear up the grammar, etc.

Comment: thank you @Alexander, now I know what im looking for. And i´m going try to improve the quality.

Comment: I right clicked your title and selected 'Search Google for ...' and selected the the first result which isn't SO (4 good approaches):
https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/manage-different-environments-in-your-swift-project-with-ease-659f7f3fb1a6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Approach:

Idea is not keep changing the code depending on the environment

1. Create separate **Target**s for Dev and Prod
2. Set **Active Compilation Conditions** to differentiate between Dev and Prod
3. Use this flag in code to handle different scenarios
4. While testing choose different environments by choosing corresponding **Scheme**s

### 1. Create separate targets for Dev and Prod

Click on Project > Target

- Rename your existing target as `Dev`
- Add new target `Prod`

[image]

### 2. Set compilation conditions in code to differentiate between Dev and Prod

Click on Project > Dev Target > Build Settings > Active Compilation Conditions

- Add `DEV`
- Similarly add `PROD` for Prod Target

[image]

### 3. Use this flag in code to handle different scenarios

```
struct Configuration {

    #if DEV

    static let fetchURL = "<your dev URL>"
    static let postURL = "<your dev URL>"

    #elseif PROD

    static let fetchURL = "<your Prod URL>"
    static let postURL = "<your Prod URL>"

    #endif
}
```

### 4. While testing choose different environments by choosing corresponding schemes

Click on Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes

- Rename your schemes to match the targets
- Use these schemes to test and build for Dev and Prod

Comment: Separate targets for something so trivial would a huge pain in the ass. I recommend against that approach in pretty much all cases.